# Trying to import a CSV file into a database in Postgres on Linux(Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgresql-12

Using the Linux command df -Ph > metric.csv to create this output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           786M  2.2M  783M   1% /run'''
```

I login to postgres and CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE metric(filesystem varchar,size varchar,used 
    varchar,available varchar,use varchar,mounted_on varchar, PRIMARY 
    KEY(filesystem));
```

[image: DDL]

Next I'm using the COPY command to insert data into this table:

```
COPY metrics (filesystem,size,used,available,use,mounted_on) FROM '/data/metric.csv' CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  missing data for column "size"
CONTEXT:  COPY metrics, line 2: "udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev"
```

I'd appreciate any help or advice as to how to correct this so I can insert my data into the database.

Comment: Well ... Just because you call it  `metric.csv` doesn't make it a CSV file.  You explicitly specify `,` as a delimiter, and there are no commas in your `df` output; seems logical that `postgres` can't find the `size` (or any other column, for that matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
df -Ph | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}NR>1{$1=$1; print}' > metric.csv
```

As I mentioned in the comment above, your csv file isn't a csv.
The awk command gets rid of the "header" (which I assume you **don't** want ingested in the table) and replaces the *spaces* with *commas*.

A few explanatory words regarding the awk - statement.

In the `BEGIN{}`  section processing takes place before awk actually tackles any input. What we tell awk here to use `,` as the output field separator (**OFS**). By default awk uses *any number of consecutive whitespace*.

`NR>1` tells awk to skip the first line (NR == number of record), thus omitting the header.

`{$1=$1;print}` - the assigning of the first field to itself is unfortunately necessary for awk to process the line; the `print` just does exactly what you think it does.

Comment: @Zedu - does the explanation help?